# nmap scanning - What is the difference between -sP and -sn?

Tags: nmap

On the Nmap home page in my language, I can see **-sP** scan, but on the English version of the site, I can't see it. But I see **-sn** that looks very similar, I want to understand what's the difference.

Comment: [`-sn` is the new syntax of `-sP`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120197/nmap-sp-scan-question#comment219133_120197)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.  To quote `man nmap`:

```
In previous releases of Nmap, -sn was known as -sP.
```

Comment: Many of the man page translations are very out-of-date. Nmap still understands `-sP`, but the documentation has switched to `-sn` (no port scan) in order to match `-Pn` (no host discovery) and `-n` (no reverse-DNS name resolution).